# I am unable to ssh into AD domain after running devsec.hardening.ssh_hardening role

Tags: networking, 20.04, ssh, ansible

I first ran the command ansible-galaxy collection install devsec.hardening

And then I ran this playbook

```
- hosts: linux
  become: yes
  vars:
    - sftp_enabled: true # Enabled for Ansible. See the Ansible scp_if_ssh option as an alternative.
    - ssh_server_password_login: true
  roles:
    - devsec.hardening.ssh_hardening
```

After this I have been unable to login into the domain user once this ssh hardening role was run

I get the error : Permission denied(public key)

The role : https://github.com/dev-sec/ansible-ssh-hardening

Comment: What does this have to do with Ubuntu?

Comment: Asked this question on SO and was redirected here.
I'm trying all this on Ubuntu 20.04